# What does 権威 mean when referring to goods?

Tags: meaning

Looking online it looks like it means either:

1. 他の者を服従させる威力
2. ある分野において優れたものとして信頼されていること。その分野で、知識や技術が抜きんでて優れていると一般に認められていること。また、その人。オーソリティー。

Obviously definition one doesn't make any sense in context, however I am not quite sure if the second definition fits this situation. Can this word be used to refer to products for sale that are one step above the competition (for example water that is good for your health, etc...).

> Character 1「ちなみに、この井戸の水を詰めて、他領地に売る商売なんかもあるわよ。飲むと健康にいい気がする、お米が美味しく炊ける気がする、植物の成長が早くなる気がすると言った効果で大人気なんだとか」
>
> Character 2「全部気がする、なんだな……」
>
> Character 3「そこまで商魂たくましいと、さすがに教会に怒られる気がする……」
>
> Character 1「**権威がつけば**ある程度は売れちゃうからねぇ」
>
> Character 4「ど、どうなんでしょうね……」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, 権威 refers to famous people, places or organizations which can endorse the quality of the goods. 権威を付ける (or 権威付け) refers to the assurance or recommendation from such entities.

Near the end of a movie trailer, we often see comments showing how the movie is appreciated, e.g., "Best Sci-Fi Ever — ABC Report", "Nominated for five XYZ Awards". Here "ABC Report" and "XYZ Awards" are 権威, and such comments are called 権威付け.

In your example, if this water is coming from a famous place, the place name itself can be a 権威. お米が美味しく炊ける itself is not a 権威, but if the church recommends the water saying this, it is called a 権威付け because the church is a 権威.

Comment: Thanks for this. I should probably have clarified this in the question that the 井戸 is located in a place of religious importance (and hence the churches involvement).

Comment: @tempytemper Okay, then this 権威 refers to both the church and the sacred place.

Comment: One last question to make sure I understand(in context) what Character 1 is saying: that if this water is recommended / endorsed then it will sell well. However, after thinking about it again, it isn't clear to me, but it might be to a native, who is saying these comments 「飲むと健康にいい気がする、お米が美味しく炊ける気がする、植物の成長が早くなる気がする」 about the water (whether it is the people buying the water, or those selling the water)). From character 3's comment it looks like they are saying that if those selling the water are saying this, then they would be told off by the church however I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps I should post a separate question for this.

Comment: @tempytemper I think I need more context to answer your question. I don't know how these characters are related to the church, after all.

Comment: They are travelers who happened to be visiting this place and not directly related to the church.

Comment: @tempytemper Probably sellers are saying 美味しく炊ける (without 気がする) and customers are saying 美味しく炊ける気がする, but it's not clear to me, either.